# Socket.ReceiveAsync and SslStream

Tags: c#, sockets, sslstream

It seems that I cannot get the benefit of ReceiveAsync when using SslStream since I will have to do the reading through SslStream, which only supports the Begin* End* async model.

Is it possible to just use SslStream until authentication is done, and from then on just access the socket directly?  This means I would have to find out what level of security was negotiated, and then apply the correct encryption/decryption to the buffers myself.  Encryption before sending, and decryption after receiving.

Is this doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SslStream is giving you privacy + server auth, and depending on whether you use ClientCertificates, Client authentication as well. You cannot use the socket directly, because once the SSL session is established, the key exchange would have bound the encryption and other algorithms to the session, and it is not possible to duplicate that in code.

Anyway, SslStream.Begin/End methods give you the async functionality you need. Why do you need to fall back to Socket.SendAsync/ReceiveAsync() ?

Comment: Then we can use SocketAsyncArgs to improve the socket performance!

Comment: No you cant. Realize that SSLStream is wrapping a stream to provide authentication and encryption. It is not wrapping Sockets. Wrapping a stream gives you the flexibility to use your own implementation of stream. If you really want better performance, write your own Stream class that implements BeginSend/EndSend by calling Socket.SendAsync()/ReceiveAsync(). Or, open a bug on http://msconnect and ask them to expose the SendAsync() pattern on all System.Net streams, whcih should solve your problem as well.